# How can I get the word preceding the last occurrence of a substring?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I am trying to get the required word by applying a regex pattern to the whole string.

Here is my string:

```
Birla Sun Life Global Real Estate Fund - Retail Plan - Direct Plan - Growth Option

SBI GOLD FUND - DIRECT PLAN - DIVIDEND
```

I want to get `Plan` type which is `Direct`

Sometimes `Plan` appears once and sometimes twice, so the pattern must work for both cases.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
$pname = 'Birla Sun Life Global Real Estate Fund - Retail Plan - Direct Plan - Growth Option';

if ( $pname =~ / ([^\s]*) plan(?!^plan$)*/ig ) # regex to get plan type
{
    $plan_type = $1;
}
print "$1";
```

But it gives the output `Retail` instead of `Direct`.

What should I do so that I can get `Direct` as the `Plan` type?

Comment: What does it mean "_Plan type which is Direct_"? What specific phrase or word from the string do you need?

Comment: Are you trying to get the word before the last occurrence of `Plan`?

Comment: Did you try it with https://regex101.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\w+)\s+Plan(?!.*Plan)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/FGtzrN/3)

[Run the perl code here](http://ideone.com/sF3YsZ)

```
use strict;

my $str = 'Birla Sun Life Global Real Estate Fund - Retail Plan - Direct Plan - Growth Option\';  ';
my $regex = qr/(\w+)\s+Plan(?!.*Plan)/p;

if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "$1";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But it will not work for me,because here I give one example, but I have some other strings in which Plan is single time, So that I need reg-ex which give just ahead string before plan,but plan should   be right side of whole word,please see my edited question again....

Comment: You need explain the business better, other no body can help you... do you want the text just before the last occurance of plan ?

Comment: yes,exactly I need the text just before the last occurrence of plan

Comment: @Sanket Try now again

Comment: @Sanket: You have not accepted answer to any of your questions. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: @Borodin I think it is cheap to downvote an accepted answer when it is already accepted, unless you comment the reason for downvoting it

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: Do you think it's as cheap as tit-for-tat voting? Whether or not your answer has been accepted has no bearing on its quality, especially when you have *asked* the OP to accept it. I have often seen accepted answers that are simply wrong and won't do what is requested. I feel this solution is unnecessarily complicated and, given the level of the OP's skills, they are unlikely to understand how it works. It is never the best idea to leave someone with black box code that they couldn't fix if they needed to.

Comment: The beginner op has asked 5-6 questions, and hasnt accepted one as answer. It is fair to let him know that, there exists a link to accept answer... and look at his response, it says it served his problem as needed... and what is right for u, may be wrong for me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. A magic regex is (IMO) rarely the right solution to a problem.

Why not instead, try `split` your fields on the delimiters (`-`):

```
my $str = 'Birla Sun Life Global Real Estate Fund - Retail Plan - Direct Plan - Growth Option'; 

my ( $fund, $something, $type, $option ) = split /\s*-\s*/, $str;
print $type,"\n";
```

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure that there are always four fields!

Answer (score -1):

To get the *last* occurrence of anything in a string, you can start the regex pattern with a greedy match that consumes as much of the string as possible

Here's a solution using your own data. Note that your global `/g` modifier is superfluous at best, and really doesn't make sense

I've also added the `/x` modifier, which allows  me to add insignificant white space to the pattern to make it more readable. It's useful on all but the most trivial of patterns

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $pname = 'Birla Sun Life Global Real Estate Fund - Retail Plan - Direct Plan - Growth Option';
my $plan_type;

if ( $pname =~ / .* \b (\w+) \s+ plan \b /ix ) {
    $plan_type = $1;
}

print $plan_type // 'undef', "\n";
```

#### output

```
 Direct
```